# How to write query for following output in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Requirements: I want to show the stock for particular B_Name, if date are same it will show on same row,  if date are not same it will show on different row and also '-' will be specify

Two tables namely gr and frosted

```
table gr:
B_Name  B_Date         B_Qty   
A       2015-08-11     15000    
A       2015-08-15     25000      
A       2015-08-31     20000
```

table frosted:

```
M_Name       M_Date       M_Qty   
    A       2015-08-11    15000    
    A       2015-08-25    25000      
    B       2015-08-20    20000 
    A       2015-08-15    15000
```

Following output:

```
             for Particular B_Name like here (A)
     Date        Inward(B_Qty) Outward(M_Qty)
    2015-08-11     15000      15000
    2015-08-15     25000      15000
    2015-08-31     20000        -
    2015-08-25      -         25000
```

I tried join and union but it is not working as per my requirements.

Comment: Why both MySQL and Oracle tags? Are both products used here?

Comment: please show your join attempt

Comment: Whatever rdbms are you using, mysql or oracle, you are looking for *LEFT JOIN*.

Comment: As @amdixon said, you should use `LEFT JOIN` because some items from your table **frosted** may not be existing for the same date as items of the table **gr**.

Comment: @jarlh NO just mysql..

Comment: @amdixon SELECT B_Date as Date,sum(B_Qty),sum(M_Qty) FROM gr
LEFT JOIN frosted ON gr.ID = frosted.IDwhere gr.B_Name='A'group by gr.B_Date
UNIONSELECT M_Date as Date,sum(B_Qty),sum(M_Qty) FROM gr
LEFT JOIN frosted ON gr.ID = frosted.ID where frosted.B_Name='A' 
group by frosted.M_Date

Comment: @RubahMalam  I tried left join but here it output  
B_Date  B_Qty  M_Qty   
2015-08-11 25000 15000 
2015-08-12 15000 15000 
2015-08-11 25000 25000 
2015-08-12 15000 25000 
2015-08-11 25000 15000 
2015-08-12 15000 15000

Comment: shouldnt the join be on dates not id ? otherwise please post sample data of id and clarify this point

Comment: @amdixon sorry that was wrong query.Just tell me how to write a query for above output..

Comment: @Zeratops I tried the left join but output is not as per the above output.

Answer (score 1):

You want records from table gr that have no match in table frosted and vice versa. So you need a full outer join, which MySQL doesn't support.

A possible workaround: Get all dates with a union query first, then outer join the tables again.

```
select 
  alldates.value as "Date",
  coalesce(g.b_qty, '-') as "Inward(B_Qty)",
  coalesce(f.m_qty, '-') as "Outward(B_Qty)"
from
(
  select b_date as value from gr
  where b_name = 'A'
  union 
  select m_date from frosted
  where m_name = 'A'
) all_dates
left join gr g on g.b_date = all_dates.value
               and g.b_name = 'A'
left join frosted f on f.m_date = all_dates.value
                    and f.m_name = 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks for the query .Please correct me, if am i wrong ,here all_dates.value will be gr.B_Date,frosted.M_Date

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and found the required result:

```
SELECT table1.bdate as "Date",coalesce(t1.B_Qty,'-') as "Inward(B_Qty)",coalesce(t2.M_Qty,'-') as "Outward(M_Qty)" FROM ( select B_date as bdate,B_Name as bname from gr union select M_Date as mdate,M_Name as mname from frosted) as table1 LEFT JOIN gr as t1 ON t1.B_Date = table1.bdate LEFT JOIN frosted as t2 ON t2.M_Date = table1.bdate WHERE table1.bname like 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Just one more question,how to replace the NULL from this symbol '-' or 0

Comment: I have updated query to replace NULL to "-", let me know is it useful :-)

Comment: .Please help me out,this query is working fine but It duplicating the value.